# NodeJS continues executing before object finished initializing

Tags: node.js

I'm creating an object in node like this:

obj.push(new MyObject());

here is my object code

```
function MyObject() {
    this.arr= [];
    for (x= 0; x< 2; x++) {
        this.arr.push([]);
        for (y= 0; y< 400; y++) {
            this.arr[x].push([]);
            for (z= 0; z< 1008; z++) {
                this.arr[x][y].push(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after I call obj.push, program execution continues and the operations at index 1006, 1007... don't work because I suspect the array isn't finished initializing. How can I make sure that the array is initialized before program execution continues?

edit:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        (function(i) {
            asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
                obj.push(new MyObject());
                some_class.bigOperation(obj[i], function() {
                    callback();
                });
            });
        })(i);
}

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function() {
    console.log("finished initializing");
});
```

Comment: This code *will* execute synchronously. In what context is the code that *calls* it executing?

Comment: It's being instantiated inside an async task that I'm executing in parallel

Comment: ... Well, if the code that calls it is async, then the mainline code will continue running while the async code runs. You need to either not run it async, or do something like run it in a promise and continue the code that relies on it in its resolution, or give the async code a callback, etc.

Comment: but the async function has both obj.push(new MyObject()) then array operations. shouldn't the push and operations be syncronous instead of asyncronous?

Comment: Without any context it's difficult to reason about what's happening. The code contained entirely within the async block will execute how you'd expect. *Outside* of the async block, code that uses values generated *within the async block* will see non-deterministic results if it does not explicitly wait, using some mechanism, for the async initialization to complete.

Comment: I updated my original post with more context. hopefully that will help

Comment: There is still missing code here. Where is obj defined?

Comment: it is defined globally like so 'var obj = []'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by array isn't initialized. You're creating your objects in parallel, which depending on your actual implementation might be the problem. Take a look at this version and see if it helps.

```
var async = require('async');
var asyncTasks = [];
var obj = [];

function bigOperation(myObj, done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('done with long operation');
    done();
  }, 1000);
}

function MyObject() {
  this.arr = [];
  for (x= 0; x< 2; x++) {
    var xlayer = [];
    this.arr.push(xlayer);
    for (y= 0; y< 400; y++) {
      var ylayer = [];
      xlayer.push(ylayer);
      for (z= 0; z< 1008; z++) {
        ylayer.push(0);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('obj created');
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var myObj = new MyObject();
  obj.push(myObj);

  (function(myObj) {
    asyncTasks.push(function(callback) {
      bigOperation(myObj, callback);
    });
  })(myObj);
}

console.log('starting async tasks');
async.parallel(asyncTasks, function() {
    console.log("finished initializing");
});
```

Comment: ahh this still throws the same error im having. my bigoperation is calling some sql and somehow I get this error: Cannot set property '1007' of undefined. And I know the only properties i'll be setting are instantiated from MyObject()... not sure what's going on here

Comment: We would need to see more of bigoperation to know what the problem is. The arrays are fully initialized before any of the async calls are made.

Answer (score -1):

use callback, node is async, code is executing line by line but will not wait

```
initialize = function(callback){
   var a = []; 
   //do your initialization here

   callback(a);
}

initialize(function(data){
   // array initialized you can now populate it.
});
```

However, you loop is a bit weird to me. Are you sure you it is correct ?

Comment: it seems to work fine whenever it does get initialized in time.